# Problem getting real html code in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, graphql, instagram, htmlunit

When I open https://www.instagram.com/metallica/ in browser and view its source code, I see javascript variable ***window._sharedData*** containing "graphql" field

When I get this page by HtmlUnit, variable ***window._sharedData*** is not the same

What's the problem? How can I get the same js field as in browser using HtmlUnit?

```java
BrowserVersion my = new BrowserVersionBuilder(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52)
    .setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)").build();

WebClient webClient = new WebClient(my);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);

HtmlPage htmlPage = webClient.getPage("https://www.instagram.com/metallica/");
String pageContent = htmlPage.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

***UPD***

window._sharedData in Browser: {"config":{"csrf_token":"zkBxaROkhJqxHV7QAYKvHYNU8QCP15vm","viewer":null,"viewerId":null},"country_code":"RU","language_code":"ru","locale":"ru_RU","entry_data":{"ProfilePage":
window._sharedData in response: {"config":{"csrf_token":"Rpm5P3Ok3ZUh7wVklBLPkMzw9k3u1tbz","viewer":null,"viewerId":null},"country_code":"RU","language_code":"en","locale":"en_US","entry_data":{"LoginAndSignupPage":

so the difference in LoginAndSignupPage instead of ProfilePage

***UPD2***

On my server instagram for unknown reason redirects any address to /accouts/login that's why content is different. So now the question is how can I prevent this redirect?

Comment: It might be worth using `client.waitForBackgroundJavascript` and enable the Ajax sync might help `client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController())`. Though I am currently having issues with some JS heavy pages

Comment: @Gavin not helped

Answer (score 0):

getWebResponse returns the response you got from the server. If you like to get the current state of the page you have to wait for the js in the page to finish and then use something like page.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage().asXML();

If you compare with a real browser please make sure

- there are no cookies stored by the browser because HtmlUnit always starts with an empty cookie store
- enable JavaScript for HtmlUnit

Comment: this solution not helped :(